# Why the error messages in GEE in time of calculation of EBBI ? EBBI: Layer error: Parameter 'value' is required

Tags: google-earth-engine

While i am trying to calculate Enhanced Built-Up and Bareness Index (EBBI) in google earth engine using the code below is showing the error message of EBBI:

> Layer error: Parameter 'value' is required.

```
// calculation of EBBI
var EBBI = SWIR1.subtract(NIR).divide (10 * Math.sqrt(SWIR1.add(TIRS1)))
//var EBBIc = EBBI.clip(roi)
Map.centerObject(roi,8)
Map.addLayer(EBBI,imageVisParam5, 'EBBI')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2FSMC_Sentinel_1%2FDEMO%3AIndex%20Landsat%208

Comment: Your code link is broken "*Repository "users/SMC_Sentinel_1/DEMO" does not exist.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to run your script. Use the `Get Link` button in the Code Editor to share your script.

By just looking at your snippet, it seems like you are trying to perform client-side operations on a server-side object. `SWIR1.add(TIRS1))` is an `ee.Image()`, a server-side object, and `10 * Math.sqrt(...)` is are client-side operations. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) section of the docs to understand why this doesn't work. Try this instead:

```
var EBBI = SWIR1.subtract(NIR).divide(SWIR1.add(TIRS1).sqrt().multiply(10))
```